# Reading data from file into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, file, ifstream

The program output Should be:

> The numbers are: 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 108 110

But my output is:

> The numbers are: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1606416272 32767

This is my code:

```
// This program reads data from a file into an array.

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // To use ifstream
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 10; // Array size
    int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE];   // Array number with 10 elements
    int count = 0;             // Loop counter variable
    ifstream inputFile;        // Input file stream object

    // Open the file.
    inputFile.open("TenNumbers.rtf");

    // Read the numbers from the file into the array.
    while (count < ARRAY_SIZE && inputFile >> numbers[count]){
        count++;
    }

    // Close the file.
    inputFile.close();

    // Display the numbers read:
    cout << "The numbers are: ";
    for (count = 0; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++){
        cout << numbers[count] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the contents of the TenNumbers.rtf file I'm reading the data from:

```
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
```

UPDATE 1:
I tried using txt file but the results are similar.

> The numbers are: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1573448712 32767

UPDATE 2:
I found where the issue was. After running `if (inputFile.good())` I found out the file was not getting opened.

Comment: Check state of `inputFile` after opening and each `inputFile >> numbers[count]` operation separately to make sure there is no errors in loading from the file. Also consider what should happen if the file contained less than `ARRAY_SIZE` numbers. I would also suggest using `std::array` or `std::vector` which perform more checks in good debuggers.

Comment: I do not really know the .rtf format. Are you sure it stores the text in an ASCII compatible format? If not, that might be the problem. A quick glance over the wiki page suggests that it at least might contain extra formatting characters. Try with a normal .txt file.

Comment: I tried using txt file but the results are similar.  `The numbers are: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1573448712 32767`

Comment: Possible duplicates: [c++ read file array](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+file+array&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: I compiled your source code and executed it, it runs perfectly, probably you are tring to open a file that does not exist. Check the names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I have compiled your code, with the .txt it runs well, without gives the strage numbers that you see.
So probably you are opening a file that does not exists, or can not be red.

```
// This program reads data from a file into an array.

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // To use ifstream
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    ifstream inputFile("c.txt");        // Input file stream object

    // Check if exists and then open the file.
    if (inputFile.good()) {
        // Push items into a vector
        int current_number = 0;
        while (inputFile >> current_number){
            numbers.push_back(current_number);
        }

        // Close the file.
        inputFile.close();

        // Display the numbers read:
        cout << "The numbers are: ";
        for (int count = 0; count < numbers.size(); count++){
            cout << numbers[count] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }else {
        cout << "Error!";
        _exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This snippet checks if the file exists, raises an error if not, and uses a vector(more suitable in c++)

Answer (score 1):

Your file name has `rtf` as suffix. Does it contain any [RTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) info in it?

The error that I see in your code is that you are assuming `ARRAY_SIZE` number of `int`s were successfully read when you are printing the numbers.

Use:

```
// Display the numbers read:
cout << "Number of ints read: " << count << std::endl;
cout << "The numbers are: ";
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    cout << numbers[i] << " ";
}
```

This will, most likely, reveal any problems in reading the data.

Comment: quick side note: don't use count as a variable name unless you dont do using namespace std;

Answer (score 1):

`ARRAY_SIZE` is the number of `int`s you allocated in the array; that is, it is the max number of `int`s.

`count` is the actual number of ints read from the file. So your final loop should go up to `count` since that is the number of actual data. So the loop that prints your data should be:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    cout << numbers[count] << " ";
```

Or you can walk a pointer:

```
int *start;

for (start = numbers; (numbers - start) < count; ++numbers)
    cout << *numbers << " ";
```

Also, I think the file extension should be "txt" rather than "rtf", but that doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

An *RTF* file is not just plain text (it's surrounded by markup) and the character encoding may differ, thus resulting in wrong interpretation of the numbers.

So, in your reading loop:

```
// Read the numbers from the file into the array.
while (count < ARRAY_SIZE && inputFile >> numbers[count]){
    count++;
}
```

the input stream `inputFile` by default is skipping white spaces which in your case could be encoded differently, thereby skipped or messed up in some way.

Note: Try and add a *test line* that prints the read number before you store it in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I had met this problem before too. I copy the content into a new file and save as different name. Then it will be fine when run it again.